# How can I send a period with the Sendkeys.SendWait() function?

Tags: c#, .net, sendkeys, keystrokes

How do I send a period using sendkeys? I have tried:

```
System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait("{.}"); 
System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait(".");
```

but neither of these work. I am trying to send the keyboard shortcut to a Google search window to enable voice search in Chrome. The shortcut is CTRL+SHIFT+PERIOD, I know how to do the ctrl+shift, just not the period. Anyone have any ideas? Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Just to clarify, you already tried `System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait("^%.")` and that didn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: `System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait(Keys.OEMPeriod);`

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered the [Keys enum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keys.aspx)? It has a "decimal"

```
System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait(Keys.Decimal)
```

Comment: I think it can send "." or "," depending on OS language or regional settings

Comment: The question wants `Keys.OEMPeriod`, which is distinct from `Keys.Decimal`.